背景画像に文字を重ねたいです
上から2枚目の画像にMENUという文字を重ねたいのですがposition:absolute;やposition:relative;を使ってやってみたのですが反映されません。
又、本来上の背景画像と下の背景画像は違う写真なのですが、同じ画像が反映されてしまいます。こちらも解決方法わかりますでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。
HTMLソース
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>COFFEE</title>
    <meta name="description" content="テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <section class="header" id="header1">
            <div class="bg-img"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav class="headerlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="#menu">MENU</li>
                        <li id="about">ABOUT</li>
                        <li id="location">LOCATION</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1 class="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="COFFEE">
                </h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>

    <!----------------------------main------------------------------>

    <main>
        <section class="menu">
            <div class="bg-img"></div>
            <h2 class="menulogo">MENU</h2>
            <div class="wrapper">

            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

CSSソース
@charset "UTF-8";

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-img {
    background-image: url(../img/mainvisual.jpg);
    background-image: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.headerlist {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.headerlist ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    gap: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.headerlist li {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}

/*----------------------main--------------------*/

.bg-img {
    background-image: url(../img/menu.jpg);
    background-image: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.menulogo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

